# Proof of Wronskian relation using induction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, induction, wronskian

We have the following linear homogenous DE system

$X' = AX, \tag 0$

I wanna prove with induction that

$dW/dx = Tr(A)*W$

So for n=2

based on the above, we get,

$A = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{bmatrix}, \tag 1$

and

$X = \begin{bmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} \end{bmatrix}, \tag 2$

we have

$X' = \begin{bmatrix} x_{11}' & x_{12}' \\ x_{21}' & x_{22}' \end{bmatrix} = AX =  \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11}x_{11} + a_{12}x_{21} & a_{11}x_{12} + a_{12}x_{22} \\ a_{21}x_{11} + a_{22}x_{21} & a_{21}x_{12} + a_{22}x_{22} \end{bmatrix}; \tag 3$

we define the Wronskian

$W = \det \left (  \begin{bmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} \end{bmatrix} \right ) = x_{11}x_{22} - x_{12}x_{21}; \tag 4$

we compute, using (3):

$W' = x_{11}'x_{22} + x_{11} x_{22}' - x_{12}'x_{21} - x_{12} x_{21}'$
$= (a_{11}x_{11} + a_{12}x_{21})x_{22} + x_{11}(a_{21}x_{12} + a_{22}x_{22}) - (a_{11}x_{12} + a_{12}x_{22})x_{21} - x_{12}(a_{21}x_{11} + a_{22}x_{21})$
$= a_{11}x_{11}x_{22} + a_{22}x_{11}x_{22} - a_{11}x_{12}x_{21} - a_{22}x_{12}x_{21}$
$= a_{11}(x_{11}x_{22} - x_{12}x_{21}) + a_{22}(x_{11}x_{22} - x_{12}x_{21}) = (a_{11} + a_{22})(x_{11}x_{22} - x_{12}x_{21}) = \text{Tr}(A) W. \tag 5$

But i cannot figure out the induction step. I would really apreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think $W$ is the Wronskian that people usually talk about... it's just a determinant right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian

Comment: Maybe this is related to Liouville's Formula
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_formula

Comment: Please do not delete your question after getting an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person or people who took the time to answer your question, and disrespectful to future readers who might find the answer helpful.

Comment: The answers I received did not help me because I needed to proceed with a specific method... that's why I deleted. This way I feel forced looking at something that is unrelevant to me.

Comment: If the answer you get does not solve your problem, do *not* vandalize your question so that the answer is invalidated.  Ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I have to use induction method.

If you are allowed to use [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) things will be even more straight forward.
$$
\frac{d\det X(t)}{dt}=\det X(t) tr(X(t)^{-1}\frac{dX(t)}{dt})\\
=\det X(t) tr(X(t)^{-1}AX(t))\\
=\det X(t) tr(AX(t)X(t)^{-1})\\
=tr(A)\det X(t)
$$

---

If Jacobi's formula is not allowed, here is a limit that could prove the target formula
$$
\frac{d\det X(t)}{dt}=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0 } \frac{\det X(t+\epsilon)-\det X(t)}{\epsilon}\\
=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0 }\frac{\det (X(t)+AX(t)\epsilon + o(\epsilon^2))-\det X(t)}{\epsilon}
$$
In the following I'll abbreviate $X(t)$ as $X$
$$
\frac{d\det X}{dt}=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0 }\frac{\det ((I+\epsilon A)X)-\det X}{\epsilon}\\
=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0 }\frac{\det (I+\epsilon A)-1}{\epsilon}\det X\\
=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0 }\frac{\prod_i (1+\epsilon A_{ii})+o(\epsilon^2)-1}{\epsilon}\det X\\
=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0 }\frac{1 + \epsilon\sum_i A_{ii}+o(\epsilon^2)-1}{\epsilon}\det X\\
=tr(A) \det X
$$
In this process, I discard terms that are proportional to $\epsilon^2$ (denoted as $o(\epsilon^2)$) since they will vanish in the limit of the quotient.

Comment: At your second solution how did you go from $detX(t+\epsilon)$ to $det(X(t)+AX(t)\epsilon+o(\epsilon^2))$ ?

Comment: Ah its the taylor expansion of the solution curve $X(t)$ at $t$. The first term is the derivative $X'(t)$